# Oscillatory Motion and SHM

Tags: harmonic-oscillator

My books states that SHM is that oscillatory motion which can be expressed in Simple sin and cos terms. What does simple  actually means ? What's the  criteria  that make  sin/cos expression simple ?

Comment: The sine and cosine functions are considered elementary functions that have simple definitions, simple behavior, simple properties, and wide applicability.

Answer (score 2):

In general, "simple" harmonic motion means that the amplitudes are (relatively) small enough for the compliance to be linear and for the inertance to not change with displacement. It also means that if there is damping present, it is "ideal" in the sense that it is linearly proportional to the velocity of the oscillation.

For mechanical engineering systems, it also means that none of the terms in the equation for the inertance, compliance and resistance elements are explicit functions of time (the condition of *constant coefficients*).

Answer (score 0):

The differential equation which can be used as a definition of simple harmonic motion, $\dfrac{d^2x}{dt^2}=-\omega^2\,x$, has the general solution $x=A\sin(\omega t) + B \cos(\omega t)$ where $A$ and $B$ are constants which can be found if two initial conditions are given.

> What does simple actually means?
>   What's the criteria that make sin/cos expression simple?

The solution to the differential equation is a linear combination of a sine term and a cosine term.

Comment: after using differential equation i am finding that x= sin(√/√m)*t .after comparing it with general sin equation I came up with (√k/√m)*t=2π (period ) squaring both sides and after rearrangement k = 4π^2*m/t how is this equal to ?

Comment: $\omega=\frac{2\pi}{T}$ where $T$ is the period of the motion.

Answer (score 0):

A mathematical theorem, due to Fourier, tells us that the most general oscillatory motion can always be written as a (possibly infinite) sum of movements, each proportional either to $sin(\omega_i t)$ or to $cos(\omega_i t)$, for a suitable set of $\omega_i$.

Therefore, the case of a single $\omega_i$ should be considered as *simple*.